# Split lines by a character or whitespace python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to split the lines in the data file I'm playing with. [This](https://gist.github.com/bodieskate/5820811) was originally someone else's code, just trying to 'fix it'. They have it splitting on a semi-colon, but I realized that they actually need it to split on excess whitespace as well. I've singled my problem out to the expression in line 28. I was trying some suggestions from other users, but when I use a regex command I get an `invalid literal for int()` warning. This is confusing because it works if I don't use the regex. Any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT: Edited for full code link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `.split` with no arguments is the only form that splits on any whitespace.

Use a regex like this:

```
re.split(r'[\s;]+', text)
```

Comment: I'm getting this as an error after trying your suggestion `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VizierConvert.py", line 28, in <module>
    s=re.split(r'[\s;]+', t) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 167, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: @Matt you should be splitting `line` and not the file `t`

Comment: Ugh, now I'm getting this....`File "VizierConvert.py", line 48, in <module>
    if(int(model[i+25][6])==3):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.51e-03'
`

Comment: @Matt That error is unrelated but that number is a `float` not `int`

Comment: More generally `split()` with a `None` argument (which is the default) splits on any whitespace.

Comment: @jamylak The second problem I'm having is weird to me though, because it has no issues printing out the values as it is now. But when I switch the code over to your suggestion I start getting that error. I don't see why it all of a sudden can't handle it.